# How to call the javascript function one after the other with delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have the JavaScript function which iterates through array and appends image to div.when the last element in array is reached, the function invokes the flip function which scales the div, and after 3 seconds the function repeats. i.e for 3 seconds we can see the flipped content, after 3 seconds it continues again from array iteration....

I have 6 set of same functions as given below...for example flip-1, flip-2, flip-3 and so on till flip-6. now what i want to do is, i want to call flip-5 as soon as flip-1 completes 3 seconds of flip.... how can i do this?

```
function startSlidecat1(started) {
  for (var i = 0; i < footwear.length; i++) {
    var image = footwear[i][0];
    imgslidercat1(image, i / initial_del * 8000, i == footwear.length - 1);
  }
};

function imgslidercat1(image, timeout, last) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('flip-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('category-1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('category-1').innerHTML = "";
    var product = document.getElementById('category-1');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    product.appendChild(elem);
    elem.src = image;
    if (last) {            
        flip1();
    }
  }, timeout);
}
startSlidecat1();

function flip1(){    
    $('#category-1').css('display', 'none');    
    $('.box-1').delay(100).css('display', 'block');
    //$('#category-1').delay(100).addClass("closeover"); 
    $('.box-1').addClass("opensesame");  
    setTimeout(closeIt, delay_time);
    //flip2();
  }

function closeIt(){
   // $('.box-1').addClass("closesesame");
    //$('.box-1').removeClass("closesesame");     
    $('#category-1').addClass("opensesame");
    setTimeout(startSlidecat1, 400);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(flip5,3000);
```

This will call the "flip5" function after 3 seconds ( = 3000ms).